# Missing charset attribute for google XML feed - validation through W3

Tags: xml, doctype, w3c-validation, xml-validation, character-encoding

I have an issue with my Google Product Feed where I am getting two warnings when using the W3 XML validator. The two warnings are:

- Warning Missing "charset" attribute for "text/xml" document.
- Warning No DOCTYPE found! Checking XML syntax only.

This is the top two lines of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" charset="UTF-8">
```

I added the charset to the rss tag in an effort to clear the warnings. I passed the validation, but I think I need to clear these warnings for Google to accept the feed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the missing charset, try changing the content type in the http header to:

`application/rss+xml; charset=utf-8`

I don't think there is an RSS 2.0 DTD. But I don't think that will matter. The Google Product Feed RSS 2.0 example in their docs doesn't include a doctype either.

Comment: I am validating the XML document through the W3 validator so I am not specifying the charset or content type in the HTTP header. I thought the w3 validator used to give you advise on how to _fix_ the problem, but there's no advice on how to resolve these two warnings. I believe it is still valid even although two warnings have been thrown.

Comment: Yes indeed. Errors are errors¹ and warnings are warnings. A warning just flags up something which is *sometimes* an authoring mistake, so that you can check for yourself whether you are happy you're doing something correctly.  (¹ Actually, with w3c standards, "errors" are really "conformance violations", but that's another story.)